# Calling a bat file (B.bat) from an exe file (A.exe)

Tags: batch-file, executable

I have two .bat files namely A.bat & B.bat
A.bat calls B.bat which ultimately calls a SAS macro for batch processing.
The whole process works as is and gives desired results.
But if I convert A.bat into A.exe and try to run, it fails to execute.
Can anyone please help?

---

A.exe

```
@echo off
call "C:\B.bat"
```

---

B.bat

```
@echo off
echo press a key to start pining
pause
ping www.google.com
pause
```

---

Comment: Why do you want to convert A.bat in A.exe? Changing the extension doesn't convert the file! It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the extension on a batch file and magically convert it into an executable. You need to leave the extension as bat. What problem were you trying to solve in renaming it?